# ng-select multiple - Change height

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

This is related to the question at [ng-select - Change height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494039/ng-select-change-height/) .  I want to do the exact same but with a ng-select that enables multiple items to be selected.

Here is my code of the ng-select:

```
<label class="col-sm-4 text-sm-right col-form-label">Payout Format</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <ng-select
                        [items]="payoutFormats"
                        [multiple]="true"
                        [closeOnSelect]="true"
                        [searchable]="true"
                        bindValue="payoutBatchFormatID"
                        bindLabel="name"
                        placeholder="All"
                        [(ngModel)]="filter.payoutFormats"
                        name="payoutFormats">
                    </ng-select>
                </div>
```

In my component I have added the following styles:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styles: [`
        .ng-select{
            font-size:0.85em;
        }

        .ng-select .ng-select-container {
            min-height: 3px;
        }

        .ng-select.ng-select-multiple .ng-select-container {
            height: 3px;
        }
  `],
})
```

I was able to get this working with a non multiple select box by using

```
.ng-select.ng-select-single .ng-select-container {
  height: 20px;
}
```

But changing it from .ng-select.ng-select-single to .ng-select.ng-select-multiple when multiple is enabled has no effect on the height.

Here is how my select looks like after the CSS:

[image]

I need it to be smaller.

**UPDATE**

In dev tools I can change min-height in .ng-select .ng-select-container as follows:

[image]

And my select box appears smaller:

[image]

However adding the same style to my component styling does not pick this up:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './list-exceptions-handling-payments.component.html',
    styles: [`
        .ng-select{
            font-size:0.85em;
        }

        .ng-select .ng-select-container{
            min-height: 3px;
        }


        .ng-select.ng-select-multiple .ng-select-container {
            height: 3px;
        }

  `],
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have overriden .ng-select-container and .ng-select-multiple which is correct but you hadn't overriden it's children elements.

Multiple select checkboxes have additional elements compared to select element (deselect button, view selected choices, etc)

These are in

```
<div class="ng-value-container">
    <div class="ng-value>
    ....
```

[image]

ng-value divs contain mendoza and franklin elements:

[image]

You need to adjust the height/line-height/margin/padding defined in these children elements.

EDIT:

You need to make your child elements smaller also before the parent element will decrease in size. E.g. in GIF:

[image]

Comment: I am basing this answer using the demo found in https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the reponse.  I am having a bit of trouble adding the styles to override. Would you please be able to specify them?

Comment: I have added a GIF showing how I I made it smaller using chrome developer tools. In future, it is better/more efficient if you trial-and-error using developer tools rather than guessing class names or css properties and waiting 2-3 seconds per refresh.

Comment: Thank you for that.  And I already did try to use the trial and error method by going in developer tools but could not get what I wanted.

Comment: So I used dev tools if I change the min-height property in .ng-select .ng-select-container it works but if I specify this in my stylesheet it is not getting picked up. Any idea why that is? I have included this in my original question.

Comment: You probably need to add `:host ::ng-deep` in-front of your css selectors. I had asked a similar question before... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717527/angular-how-to-change-an-imported-components-class-to-change-color

Answer (score 0):

In case you also ran into this questions for the reason that a multi select box is higher than a normal select box that can be fixed as follows ( we only do the top padding if there are actual selected items in there

```
.ng-select.ng-select-multiple .ng-select-container .ng-value-container{
  padding-top:0;
}

.ng-select.ng-select-multiple .ng-select-container .ng-value-container:has(div.ng-value){
  padding-top:5px;
}
```